# Positioning a Div at the center of the web page bneath a div

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage which contains a header at the top.

Beneath to which is another div that i want to position at the center of the screen with width `960px` but the second `div` is displaying to the far right.

Also there are dropdown menu in header menu,that too is not click-able.

Here is the sample HTML..

```
 <div class="header-wrapper">
   //Mark up for header with drop-down.
 </div>

 //Second Div ..
 <div id="slideshow-carousel" class="center">               

 </div>
```

CSS..

```
.header-wrapper {
  background: url("../img/new_images/bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 60001;     
  width: 100%;
  height: 77px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}


.center {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:960px;; 
}
```

Full markup for second DIV

```
<div id="slideshow-carousel" class="center">                
        <ul id="carousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
            <li><a href="#" rel="p1"><img src="img/new_images/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p2"><img src="img/new_images/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p3"><img src="img/new_images/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p4"><img src="img/new_images/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p5"><img src="img/new_images/" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p6"><img src="img/new_images/web.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p7"><img src="img/new_images/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And here is the complete CSS

```
 .center
        {
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            width:960px; 
            height: 565px;
        }


        #slideshow-carousel {

            width:960px;
            position:relative
        }

        #slideshow-carousel ul {
            margin:0; 
            padding:0;
            list-style:none;
        }

        #slideshow-carousel li {
            background:#fff; 
            height:583px; 
            position:relative
        }

        #slideshow-carousel li .arrow {
            left:3px; 
            top:28px; 
            position:absolute; 
            width:20px; 
            height:40px; 
            background:url(images/arrow_white.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
            display:block;
        }

        #slideshow-carousel li a {
            background:#000; 
            display:block; 
            width:960px; 
            height:583px;
        }


        #slideshow-carousel .active {
            filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
            -moz-opacity:1.0; 
            -khtml-opacity: 1.0; 
            opacity: 1.0;
        }

        #slideshow-carousel .faded {
            filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
            -moz-opacity:0.5; 
            -khtml-opacity: 0.5; 
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
```

And

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

Comment: FYI `z-index` only works when an element is positioned.

Comment: @MelanciaUK What i need to add to get the things done?

Comment: @MelanciaUK Please see this fiddle jsfiddle.net/NAJu6  and tell me how it can be possible dublicate of the smae

Answer (score 0):

Your div is a `block` element which takes up the entire available window width. hence there is no space left to center align it. simply give it a width less than window width and it'll automatically center align according to your current css.

*Side note: don't forget to add a `height` or content otherwise you won't see the `<div>` at all..*

Comment: I want the second div to show with a width of `960px` and align center to all screens regardless of the screen size till it width applicable

Comment: @user3699193 since you have set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`, it'll automatically center align horizontally in larger screens...

Comment: Then why is it not happening in my medium size screen

Comment: @please share the exact html and css you have. in the shared html & css you don't have any content, you haven't set the height either. so nothing will be visible. why it's not happening in your screen depends on what your actual code is

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NAJu6/ Please see this fiddle demo.My condition is like this only .My second div is going to the extreme right of the web page that i need to position at the center of the webpage with width of `960px` ..

Comment: @user3699193 like i said, [it's already centered](http://jsfiddle.net/NAJu6/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: Ok Sir .As per fiddle link jsfiddle.net/NAJu6 ,if i have to show to the second div at the center of the current screen without scrolling horizontal how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.center
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:960px; //Edit the size you want
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
      //Mark up for header with drop-down.
</div>

<div id="slideshow-carousel" class="center">               
      //Second div
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NAJu6/)**

Comment: My present webpage is just like yours ..Instead of showing to the `slideshow-carousel` to the extreme right i want to show it at the center of the screen ..Please help me to get it..

Comment: Can you help me in this?

Comment: Please use the jsfiddle to represent your html markup and css and i will help you

Comment: Ok Sir .With your fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/NAJu6/ ,if i have to show to the second div at the center of the current screen without scrolling horizontal how can i do it?

Comment: You must see that you setting 960px of witdh...in the fiddle you can expect a horizontal scroll, because the window size is smaller. If you set percentage you get no horizontal scrool - http://jsfiddle.net/NAJu6/2/

Comment: Ok Sir i am testing it in my browser screen too at the same time but there also getting after the horizontal scroll

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the second div...but i'm not sure because i can´t see what you are seeing with real html markups and css. If you give me a url where i can see what you see, maybe i will fix it :)

Comment: You don´t need just put in a free host...upload you files by ftp

Comment: Ok sir suppose i want to add a div with width `960px` at the center of the screen .How can i do this

Comment: I am sorry to tell but have no idea of the same

Comment: I have upadated my post with the complete Markup for the second div and its CSS>PLease help.